# NGINX filter requests to lan IP

Tags: django, nginx, mod-security

I have received several requests via NGINX that appear to be to my LAN IP 192.168.0.1 as follows:

**nginx.vhost.access.log:**

```
192.227.134.73 - - [29/Jul/2021:10:33:47 +0000] "POST /GponForm/diag_Form?style/       HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "curl/7.3.2"
```

**and from Django:**

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '192.168.0.1:443'. You may need to add '192.168.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

**My NGINX configurations as follows:**

```
upstream django_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

# Catch all requests with an invalid HOST header
server {
    server_name "";
    listen 80;
        return 301 https://backoffice.example.com$request_uri;
    }

server {
    listen 80;
    # Redirect www to https
    server_name www.backoffice.example.com;
    modsecurity on;
    modsecurity_rules_file /some_directory/nginx/modsec/modsec_includes.conf;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "deny" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    #add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https://example.com https://backoffice.example.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://code.jquery.com";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" always;

    return 301 https://backoffice.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      server_name www.backoffice.example.com backoffice.example.com;
      modsecurity on;
      modsecurity_rules_file /some_directory/nginx/modsec/modsec_includes.conf;
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;" always;
      add_header X-Frame-Options "deny" always;
      add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
      add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
      #add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https://example.com https://backoffice.example.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://code.jquery.com";
      add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"; 

      ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/nginx-ssl/backofficebundle.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/nginx-ssl/backoffice.key;
      
      access_log /some_directory/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
      error_log /some_directory/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;        
}


      location /media/ {
        alias /some_directory/backoffice/media/;
        }

        location /static/ {
        alias /some_directory/backoffice/static/;
    }

}
```

My questions:

1. Is there any way of configuring NGINX to block requests to all LAN IP's?
2. Can this be done better by ModSecurity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way of configuring NGINX to block requests to all LAN IP's?

There is, just make nginx `listen` only on the public IP (e.g. `listen backoffice.example.com:443 ssl http2;`). Although I have no idea why you'd want this…

Because if it's an *internal* IP it *cannot* be accessed externally (by definition – otherwise you wouldn't call it internal). If that would be the case you'd have more like a problem with your network/firewall.

Regarding the nginx access log, I cannot spot any problem. `192.227.134.73` is not a private IP.

Regarding the Django log, `curl -H "Host: 192.168.0.1:443" https://backoffice.example.com` would have caused such a request. The "Host" header is just a header after all that can contain anything.

Comment: Hi Slauth, thanks for your response. Can you please expand your answer to explain why it is unadvisable to block wan traffic accessing  internal ip's? What do you advise instead? Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer. What would make sense IMHO is to block requests without a valid "Host" header. Let me know if you're interested in this.